# configure zktco device to software

Tags: status, zkteco

how to connect zkteco device to software 7.0

I am working on a project to control presence in my company and i want to configure zkteco device with IP, the device is working fine but when i'm trying to synchronize data from software to device it doesn't work the device status shows device not connected